# How to extract the data frame in mp3 stream using gstreamer?

Tags: audio, gtk, mp3, frame, gstreamer

I am now trying to write a music player using Gstreamer.I know that mp3 files are made up with frames (data frame and tag frame).what i want to do is extract the data frame and calculate its hash to identify a file. what should i do?
thinks in advince!

Answer (score 1):

this all is done by gstremer **mad** element. So if you are writing application then use this element.

NOTE: mad element is comes inside gst-plugin-bad package which you can download from gstremer site